# Xamarin problem with android plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, media

i have a problem with plugin  Plugin.SimpleAudioPlayer [here](https://github.com/adrianstevens/Xamarin-Plugins/blob/main/SimpleAudioPlayer/README.md).
When I run the application from UWP everything is fine, but when I use the Android platform every time the program stops at creating a simple audio player:

```
System.NullReferenceException: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
```

i dont know how can i fix it

Code:

```
var test = CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer();
```

i have tried deleting the debug folder, changing the plugin version and restarting the emulation but nothing works

Comment: you need to start by determining which object is null

Comment: This is a problem because the error pops up in CrossSimpleAudioPlayer.CreateSimpleAudioPlayer(); and I don't have permission to look at the code

Comment: look at the stack trace of the exception

Comment: (1) Sometimes its easier to see exception details if you wrap your code in `try-catch (Exception ex)`, and then set a breakpoint in the `catch` block. (2) If this is happening before first page displays, then as a test, move the call into a button click handler. Reason: Makes sure app has completed its startup. If this works better, then that narrows down the problem; would need to see more "context"; defer when the call is made.

Comment: thank you for your answer, it was my mistake as i thought the problem was with the plugin but this problem was somewhere else. Thanks to your answer, I was able to locate the error. Thanks again for the quick replies and i think, the topic is closing :)